# How to produce difficult variant of Taegeuk symbol? (see images)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, symbols

The Republic of Korea (or, "South Korea") has a Taegeuk at the centre (essentially, a blue and red yin and yang symbol). This design is derived from the flag of the Korean Empire (used between 1882 and 1910), shown by the following two images:

[image: Illustration of Korean Empire's flag (1882 - 1910)]

[image: png of Korean Empire's flag (1882 - 1910)]

I know how to produce a regular 'yin-yang' symbol (a circle with two circles with diameters half as long), but I don't know how to make this spiral variant myself. Is there a way to do this, so that the lobes are equal in area and shape, and they tessellate to form a perfect circle? I'm using Adobe Illustrator, so answers applicable to this appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed before that the symbols around the taegeuk in the Korean flag are the hexagrams for the four elements. Learnt something new today!

Comment: They are picked from the eight original Chinese [Bagua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua), known in Korea as "Pal Gwae".

Comment: Exactly—I'd never paid enough attention to the flag to notice that before now. Guess I never really looked very closely at the flag at all.

Comment: Oh, I just realised I wrote hexagrams above. I meant trigrams, of course.

Comment: Eh. You're probably fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry about this, but I have just found the answer to my problem:

[image: image from http://www.penninetaichi.co.uk/]

Given this, I then created my own using Adobe Illustrator (seen in the following image). The outermost circle I used as one unit (in my case, 100 px diameter).

[image: my working]

Thanks anyway.

Comment: First image of answer from: http://www.penninetaichi.co.uk/index_files/image10661.jpg

Comment: While this solution be ok for your purposes, I think the shape of the spiral is a little "off" when compared to the original image. This only matters if it matters (historical accuracy, or documentative purposes etc).